# Visual Studio 2017 C++ built executable refuses to launch on another PC

Tags: c++, curl, build, visual-studio-2017

I have a `C++` project in `Visual Studio 2017`,  which I built an executable file from, using [the answer from this question found on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0699b2fd-b505-4166-979e-677e2862bf01/how-can-i-create-an-exe-file-from-a-visual-studio-project?forum=csharpgeneral) , the `.exe` was built successfully, but when I copy this file to another PC and try to launch it, it returns me an error message, which says that `launching of this app is impossible, because libcurl.dll is absent`, what should be done, for avoiding this problem ?

Here's the preset which I'm using for `.exe` creation [image: Used Preset]

## P.S.

If it is of any help, when I created the project, I've chosen `Empty Visual C++ Project`.

Comment: You also need to copy `libcurl.dll` with the executable. Put it in the same folder as you put the executable.

Comment: ... or use libcurl as static library.

Comment: I'm trying to launch the app on a clean x86 system, and I've copied the `libcurl.dll` as said, after this appeared another error with another `.dll` which I've copied too, and so on, also I've tried to install Visual C++ Redistributable, but the installer throws an error related to the fact that the machine hasn't the SP1 installed. Yes I've searched for x86 version of redistributable, but I found only an x64-x86 All in one package

Comment: The correct redistributable should be in the Visual Studio path on your hard drive.  Here is a download link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads you want x86 for 32 bit.